# passing children or css attribute to component style config chakra ui

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

Is there a possibility to pass a children prop or atleast css attribute like title to component style config in chakra ui?

[image: children]

[image: css atribute]

Answer (score 0):

When using "attr" just pass the variable as a plain string instead of wrapping it with template literals. Using children is not possible there i guess.